# Ipython Notebook: Resize figure with "handle"?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In this [IPython Notebook example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Plotting%20in%20the%20Notebook.ipynb) it says that:

> [...] images can be resized by dragging the handle in the lower right
>   corner. Double clicking will return them to their original size.

Which handle is meant by that? I don't see any in my own output.
Am I missing an extension package to see this handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

think they are referring to the small thingy marked in my screenshot. In the current version, this handle does not seem to be present for inline graphics.

If you replace `%matplotlib inline` by `%matplotlib notebook`, you can experiment with this feature.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.title('A simple chirp');
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, that made it very nice and easy!